# Vue.js, pass data to component on another route

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Simple task to pass data from one page to another made a real headache to newbie in Vue.js
Here is my router
[image]

I'm rendering a form on "/" page, which make an API request,
[image]

and I just want to pass data to another route page with another component
[image]

Is it so hard to do in Vue? It made a real headache for me today. 
Get data from API, save & send to another component. How can I do it?

Comment: what data do you want to pass? `activities`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Antony said, since you've already enabled props in `router/index.js`, you can pass parameters in `router.push` like this:

```
router.push({
    name: 'events',
    params: {
        items: data
    }
});
```

then you will be able to receive `items` as props in `EventsDisplay.vue`

```
export default {
    name: 'eventsDisplay',
    props: ['items'],
};
```

Comment: @EzhiMakov `this.items` should work. Since it's not related to this question, you can just 
open another question and paste your code there.

Comment: thanks a lot, man, sorry for previous comment, it was my stupdity with refreshing /events page without passing data

Comment: thanks it did worked.. wasted so much time.. finally got

Comment: @choasia,  May i ask you to have a look at a Vue.JS question related with the source code in github of the book 'Full-Stack Vue.js 2 and Laravel 5' by Anthone Gore here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245577/laravel-vuejs-router-view-does-not-render-the-component ? Particularly take a look at the EDIT: section of the OP

Comment: In my case (@vue/cli-service version 3.12.1), I cannot get the params through props but I get it from `this.$route.params.items`

Comment: please add       "props: true", in router prop define like this => {
      path: "/dataList",
      name: "dataList",
      props: true,
      meta: { title: "Data list" },
      component: () => import("path to datalist component")
    }

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save it globally, you could use an event bus or a VueX store  to contain it, then save and load it from this event bus or store when you need to access it.

If you want to pass it between those two components only, and only when accessing the second page from the first one, you can pass properties to the route argument as per this guide: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using **Vuex**

In Source Component

```
this.$store.commit('changeDataState', this.$data);
this.$router.push({name: 'user-post-create'});
```

In Destination Component

```
created () {
    console.log('state', this.$store);
    this.$store.getters.Data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add props true in your vue router

```
{
    path: "/pay-now",
    name: "pay",
    props: true,
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../components/account/pay.vue"),
    beforeEnter: AuthGuard,
  },
```

After that pass props with router like that

```
        this.$router.push({ 
        name: "pay",
        params: {
        result:this.result,
      }
      });
```