# how to pass data to another vue.js component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

[image]

I'm using a Vue.js template. I want to pass menuItemsData to another vue component (timeselect)(in picture 2 I push to a different component timeselect). I've looked at multiple tutorials but I don' t see how I can use `v-bind` here?

[image]

Even if I manage to push it to the other component, how would I recieve it?

Comment: Share you code as text and not as picture.

Answer (score 0):

Please look if somebody already asked a similar question, you can already find two similar questions:

[Vue.js, pass data to component on another route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484684/vue-js-pass-data-to-component-on-another-route?rq=1)

[Passing props to Vue.js components instantiated by Vue-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937262/passing-props-to-vue-js-components-instantiated-by-vue-router?rq=1)

Anyways, one solution would be to pass your data as a parameter in in `router.push` method.

Another solution you should consider if you want to use your menuItemsData in other components as well is state management with [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/).

**1. Using the `router.push` params field:**

You can either pass menuItemsData as a Parameter via `router.push`:

```
router.push({
    path: '/',
    params: {
        menuItemsData: menuItemsData
    }
});
```

Then you can receive the data in the component you linked to your root url:

```
export default {
    name: 'timeselect',
    props: ['menuItemsData'],
};
```

Don't forget to add the `props: true` option when you register the timeselect route.

```
new Router ({
  routes: [
    path: '/',
    component: timeselect,
    props: true
  ]
})
```

**2. Using vuex store for global state management:**

For the correct implementation of this concept, vuex has a very good documentation with sample code snippets.

A simple store with your data could look something like this:

```js
// Here we create the state where our data is stored
const state = {
  totalBill: 0.0,
  menuItemsData: {
    Glazed: {
      name: 'Chocolate', 
      qty: 0,
      price: 2.00
    },
    Chocolate: { 
      name: 'Glazed', 
      qty: 0,
      price: 2.00
    }
  }
}

// Here we define the getters to access our data
const getters = {
  getMenuItemsData: state => state.menuItemsData,
  getTotalBill: state => state.totalBill
}

// Here we define mutations which are used for changing our state data
const mutations = {
  addToTotalBill: (state,amount) => state.totalBill += amount
}

// Then we create a new vuex store instance containing our data and the getter, ther you would also add the Mutations for updating the data
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
  mutations
})

// Our Vue component which maps our getters to access our data from the vuex store
new Vue({
    store,
    el: '#container',
    computed: Vuex.mapGetters(['getMenuItemsData', 'getTotalBill']),
    methods: Vuex.mapMutations(['addToTotalBill'])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <!-- Now we can just access our data from the store in the component -->
    <h3> Menu Items from store: </h3>
    <li v-for="item in getMenuItemsData">
      <span>{{ item.name }} - </span>
      <span @click="addToTotalBill(item.price)" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">add to Bill</span>
    </li>
    
    <br>
    <span>Total Bill:</span>
    {{ getTotalBill }}
  </ul>
</div>
```