# Vue passing data from one page to the next

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

On my one page I have a table, where the following runs after clicking a row:

```
  public onRowDataClick(workItem){    
  this.$router.push({
    path: '/SecondPageView',
    params: {pushedData: workItem}
   });
  }
```

This is my route:

```
    {
        path: '/SecondPageView',
        name: 'SecondPage',
        component: SecondPage,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true,
        },
    },
```

The next page loads fine, and now I want to be able to use the `pushedData`, but I'm not entirely sure how this should go.

I tried following the previous stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484684/vue-js-pass-data-to-component-on-another-route), but I can't set it up in the same way due to how my class is set up? It wont let me have `props:` after my `export default ...`.

Based on reading material [here](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/props-definition.html) and the previous answer, I have set up the following:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import ...

const GreetingProps = Vue.extend({
  props: ['pushedData']
});

@Component({
  components: {
...
  },
})  

export default class Dashboard extends GreetingProps {    
  @Watch('buttonClicked')
  Log() {
    console.log(this.pushedData);
  }
}
</script>
```

This returns "undefined".
What can I do to be able to get my data object from one page to another?

Comment: Alternatively you can use Vuex store for data that will be shared between multiple pages.

Comment: I am trying this, but I'm having a hard time since all the examples seem to use vue in a different way from the vue files I've gotten. Mainly I dont have the regular `export default {}` where you can have `name:` `props:` etc. Any way to bridge this?

Comment: It looks like the file difference is mostly from Typescript. I haven't used Vue with TS before so I'm not familiar with what you have. Have you looked into Vuex-Typescript support? The examples might be more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

`params` is for path parameter.

If you have a route like this: `/user/:id`

You can do `$router.push({ name: 'user', params: { id: 'abc123' })`

and you can access the dynamic parameter's value via `$route.params.id` (no **r** on the `$route`).

If path parameter is not necessary, you can also just use query string:

`router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' } })`

It will result in: `/register?plan=private`

You can then access the value via `$route.query.plan`

Docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Although honestly you can simply just do:

`$router.push('/user/abc123')` or `$router.push('/register?plan=private')`

Comment: Hey this seems useful! I'm wondering however can it send something other than a string? I have a data object which is essentially an array of strings I'm trying to pass.

Comment: You can do `?strings[]=a&strings=b` or `?strings=a,b,c` or maybe something else like encoding it to base64. Might worth searching about how to do string array with query strings.